# Windows Authentication Project Online RestAPI

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, postman, windows-authentication

I am trying to request data from a uri in the form "https://link.sharepoint.com/sites/0001/_api/link" that requires to log in into your windows account to have access.

To test I started using Postman but can't figure out how to use Windows Auth for the request.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you should use NTLM authentication

[image]

Workstation is your computer hostname and domain is your domain used for windows authetication you can see it in internet explore when authentication pop up comes up

In username passord fields provide the credential you use for login to system